# Sum the elements of 2D array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I made 2D arrray which prints some random elements.

Now i need a method which calculates the sum of that elements but just elements below the main diagonal.

Here is my code...

```
class Init {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int n = 0;
        int m = 0;
        int aray[][];

        Random random = new Random();
        Scanner tastatura = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[][] array = new int[n][m];
        n = tastatura.nextInt();
        m = tastatura.nextInt();
        array = new int[n][m];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                array[i][j] = random.nextInt(20);
            }
        }

        for (int[] a : array) {

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));

        }

    }

}
```

I did it like this... Now i can sum, but when i try to multyply same numbers i am geting 0 Why is that?

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Unesite duzinu kolona i redova : ");    
int rows = scanner.nextInt();
int columns = rows;
int[][] matrix = new int[rows][rows];
Random random = new Random();

System.out.println("Nasumicni/random brojevi su :");
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = random.nextInt(20);

    }
}

for (int[] a : matrix) {

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));

}

//here is the logic which sum those elements
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        sum = sum + matrix[i][j];
    }

}

System.out.println("\nMatrix is : ");
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

System.out.println("Proizvod elemenata ispod glavne dijagonale je: " + sum);
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO. In general, you should try to include details about what you've tried by yourself and what problems you're having. SO isn't meant to get people to do your work *for* you, but rather to ask for help with a problem you're having; check out [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) from the FAQ

Comment: Hello, well i think that i did include some details. 
I ask people if they know or have some idea how to finish this work of mine. I did 80% of it i just don't know how to sum elements that i now have in this 2D array in specific order.

Till now i made... 1. user input (size of 2D array), 2. random elements... and now i need to sum half of that elements (i told you how).

I know to sum all elements but not this.

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
int s = 0;
for(int i = 1; i < m; ++i)
     for(int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
           s += a[i][j];
```

This **selectively** loops through the elements below the main diagonal and sums them up, without **looping through the entire matrix** and making it lengthier.

Answer (score 1):

The **main diagonal** of a matrix consists of those elements that lie on the diagonal that runs from top left to bottom right. But since you want those elements "below" the main diagonal, here is an algorithm I came up with for that.

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
     for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
           if (i == j && (i + 1 < n))
           {
                int temp = i + 1;
                while (temp < n)
                {
                    sum += arr[temp][j];
                    temp++;
                }
           }
```

Also, you declare `int[][] array` multiple times. You need to declare it only once, after you get the values for n and m.

Answer (score 0):

for(i=0;i

for(j=0;j

{

if(j>i)

d1+=a[i][j];. // Above the diagon

else

if(i>j)

d2+=a[i][j];.   // Below the diagonal

}